# Can not install NUnit because NUnit is not found

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, nuget, nunit

I had some problems with my NUnit tests not being discovered, so I wanted to re-install the NUnit NuGet package.

I uninstalled the NuGet package NUnit and now I am trying to install it.

However, when I try to install it from 'Manage Nuget packages for solution', the installation fails and I get many error messages like this one from my solution:

> CS0246  C# The type or namespace name 'NUnit' could not be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

To me this seems a bit absurd. Is the installation of NUnit failing because I don't have NUnit in my solution?

I tried cleaning and rebuilding the project but I had no luck.

Any idea about how this issue could be solved?

Comment: Look inside output window to see what the problem with the package is. CS0246 error occurs not because installation failed, but because you don't have the package (and you don't, because you uninstalled it).

Comment: Your solution needs to compile successfully for the install to work. Comment out the NUint code and install the package again.

Answer (score 0):

> Can not install NUnit because NUnit is not found

The error messages looks like a compile error NOT a NuGet install error message. That is because you uninstalled the package `NUnit`. It will always exist until you successfully install the package `NUnit`.

So, try to clean the output window, then install the package `NUnit`, and check the install log in the output window.

Besides, if you still get this error when you install the package `NUnit`, please try [user *virusstorm's* suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50232231/can-not-install-nunit-because-nunit-is-not-found#comment87489081_50232231):

> Comment out the NUint code and install the package again.